# President of [Country][Name] vs President [Name] of [Country]

Tags: phrasing, honorifics

I came across the following sentence in [The Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/nov/22/russia-ukraine-eu-pact-lithuania) (emphasis mine):

> ***President Vladimir Putin of Russia*** said the EU was putting pressure on Kiev and organising mass protests against President Viktor Yanukovych.

I've seen this construction used only for royalty, e.g.

> Prince Harry of Wales, King Stark of Winterfell, King Louis of France, etc.

On the other hand, non-royal government leaders usually seem to follow another pattern:

> Presidend of the USA Barack Obama, Prime Minister of Italy Silvio Berlusconi, etc.

Am I imagining things about this distinction or is ther truth to it? Is it possible that the unusual wording is a subtle pun or am I reading too deep into it?

Comment: Well for a start, "Prince Harry of Wales" is completely wrong. He is Prince Harry, Prince of Wales. *The Prince of Wales* is a title, not a description. He is *of* the United Kingdom.

Comment: @Matt: Wikipedia disagrees with you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Harry_of_Wales

Comment: Ah. I see. His father has the title "Prince of Wales" (i.e. it is *not* Prince Charles of Wales);  As a British prince he uses the name of the area over which his father holds title; i.e., Wales, as a territorial suffix in lieu of surname.

Comment: In fact, of course, his father is the only Prince of Wales. The Royal Family have, traditionally, no surname, except 'Elizabeth of England'.  For some purposes, particularly military, a surname is necessary, so Harry is 'Captain Wales'  and the Queen was, when she joined up in WW2, 'Lieutenant Windsor' -but not outside the Forces.

Comment: Actually related to the question:  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/71760/8019

Comment: @TimLymington: My main question is doesn't President Putin Of Russia sound odd?

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան: It doesn't sound particularly odd. If it sounded odd, I suspect the Grauniad would have chosen a different phrasing for it.

Comment: @TimLymington that hasn't been true since 1917 when George V took *Windsor* as both a house name, and a surname. All of the current British Royal Family have either the surname *Windsor* or the surname *Mountbatten-Windsor* (for the direct descendants of Elizabeth II, but keeping *Windsor* as the house name). They generally do not use their surname, but have done so during wedding vows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unusual, but not to the point of being weird.

The most common usages are exactly as you say. It remains though that a title of Putin is "President Putin", and that he is "of Russia", and so it is a valid phrasing.

It's not done as a title, but as a clarification. They first refer to him as "President Putin", and then considering that there may be some readers who don't recollect just what he is president of, they add "of Russia".

[Here](http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2013/06/15/readout-president-obama-s-call-prime-minister-cameron-united-kingdom-pre) is an example of a Whitehouse statement entitled "Readout of President Obama’s Call with Prime Minister Cameron of the United Kingdom, President Hollande of France, Prime Minister Letta of Italy, and Chancellor Merkel of Germany". In each case, it refers to each person by their title, and barring Obama (on the grounds that they assume anyone reading statements from the Whitehouse knows who the current US president is) they add their country.

[Here](http://www.whitehouse.gov/photos-and-video/photo/2013/03/president-obama-taoiseach-kenny-ireland-and-house-speaker-boehner) is another that uses "Taoiseach Kenny of Ireland", despite no other country in the world using that title. To be (in English use at least) Taoiseach entails being Taoiseach of Ireland, but again some readers may not be familiar with the office, and so his country is given as a clarification.

Of course, people are likely to be more familiar with some countries than others, but that remains a reason to use it consistently; If one didn't use it of the countries best-known to your audience, but did use it of some others, there could be a perceived slight in suggesting that those for whom you added the country are less well-known because they are less important.